# How does Python's dict manage types as keys when __hash__ and __eq__ are not callable without arguments?

Tags: python

Python doc states that dict keys must be hashable, which implies having `__hash__` and `__eq__`

I'm trying to understand how using types as keys in a dict is able to work when, by default at least, both these methods expect an instance as the first parameter.

Consider the code below and it's output:

```py
class Apple:
    pass

class Orange:
    pass

lookup = {Apple: lambda: print('Apple!'), Orange: lambda: print('Orange!')}

try:
    print(Apple.__hash__())
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    
try:
    print(Apple.__eq__())
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

an_apple = Apple()
an_orange = Orange()

lookup[type(an_apple)]()
lookup[type(an_orange)]()
```

```plaintext
descriptor '__hash__' of 'object' object needs an argument
descriptor '__eq__' of 'object' object needs an argument
Apple!
Orange!
```

How is dict both getting the hash and checking equality of the types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python doesn't look up magic methods on the instance. It looks them up on the class itself. In your case, the *class* of `Apple` is `type`.

```
>>> class Apple: pass
... 
>>> hash(Apple)
5929200437980
>>> type.__hash__(Apple)
5929200437980
```

The same thing happens for `__eq__`. This can also be seen if you try to attach magic methods to an instance rather than a class.

```
>>> class Apple:
...   def __hash__(self):
...     return 1
... 
>>> my_apple = Apple()
>>> my_apple.__hash__ = lambda: 2
>>> hash(my_apple) # 1, not 2
1
>>> my_apple.__hash__()
2
>>> Apple.__hash__(my_apple)
1
```

Note that `Apple` and `my_apple` both have `__hash__` defined on them, but it's the class' method that gets called, not the one on the instance.